# Fastlane Testflight distribute to external users

Tags: ios, app-store, fastlane

I tried to upload the IPA file to Testflight with success and when I uploaded it automatically Internal testers are added and notified of the new version applied.When I tried to add external groups stand not added. There are no errors from Fastlane. Here is my lane. Thanks!

```
 desc "Upload to Testflight"
    lane :testflight_track do
       app_identifier = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier)
       api_key = lane_context[SharedValues::APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY]
       upload_to_testflight(
       api_key: api_key,
       app_identifier: app_identifier,
       ipa:"ipaname",
       changelog: "testnotes",
       distribute_external: true,
       skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
       groups: [
           "Internal Users",
           "External Users"
       ]
    )
```

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hello, Yes you can do it in two ways.
1. Using Fastlane
`distribute_external : true` but you need to pass also `skip_waiting_for_build_processing:false` If set to true, the distribute_external option won't work and no build will be distributed to testers.
2. Using Spaceship 
You can connect to Connect API and do the job
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/testflight/testflight.rb#L176-L192

Answer (score 0):

need to remove `skip_waiting_for_build_processing`

[Documentation from fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/#parameters):

> skip_waiting_for_build_processing If set to true, the
> distribute_external option won't work and no build will be distributed
> to testers. (You might want to use this option if you are using this
> action on CI and have to pay for 'minutes used' on your CI plan). If
> set to true and a changelog is provided, it will partially wait for
> the build to appear on AppStore Connect so the changelog can be set,
> and skip the remaining processing steps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).